# Understanding rare definition of the likelihood function and corresponding posterior from research paper

Tags: regression, bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, naive-bayes, bayesian-network

Reading the paper https://storage.googleapis.com/pub-tools-public-publication-data/pdf/b20467a5c27b86c08cceed56fc72ceadb875184a.pdf i came across a rare definition of the likelihood function that in my eyes seems misspelled.
Have a look at function 8 and 9, ctrl-f "(8)" or ctr-lf "(9)" in the document.

"Let Φ denote the vector of parameters in the model in (7), X denote all the media variables,
Z denote all the control variables, and y denote the vector of response values. The frequentist
approach finds the most likely value of the parameters by maximizing the likelihood (MLE), as in $\phi_{hat} = \underset{\phi}{\operatorname{argmax}}L(y | X, Z, \phi)$

This goes against the definition known to me, it would make sence however if they substituted the L with an P indicating probability instead of likelihood. Or by substituting $\phi$ with $y$.

Similarly, the definition they use of the posterior seems really strange and has the same error as stated above.

$p(\phi|y, X) \propto L(y|X, Z, \phi)\pi(\phi)$

same case here...

Can someone shed some light onto this?

Comment: google connection removed in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Imho, there is nothing rare there with the likelihood definition or notation except for a minor mistake.**

Here is the relevant excerpt from the paper:

[image: portion of page 6 from Jin et al. (2017)]

Hence there is a clear mistake/typo in using $\mathcal L$ in both (8)$-$where it stands for a log-likelihood$-$and (9)$-$where it stands for a likelihood$-$. Assuming $\mathcal L$ stands for a likelihood  does not modify (8) and removes the double meaning.

Apart from that easily resolved ambiguity between likelihood and log-likelihood, I see no issue with this traditional and basic presentation of MLE and Bayesian approaches. The notation $\mathcal L$ or $L$ is standard for the likelihood function (with $\ell$ sometimes being used for log-likelihoods), even though the order in$$\mathcal L(y|X, Z, \phi)$$is often inverted to$$\mathcal L(\Phi|X, Z, y)$$to stress that the likelihood is a function of the parameter $\Phi$, indexed or parameterised by the observed realisation of $(X, Z, y)$.

There is no trace of a $\text{Pr}(\cdot)$ function in the paper, hence I assume you mean by this the *density function* of the distribution attached to the data $y$, but (i) this is not a standard notation as $\text{Pr}(\cdot)$ is usually denoting a probability function, which entries are events, not (continuous) random variates and (ii) the authors appear to use $\mathcal L(y|X, Z, \phi)$ as this density, which is mathematically correct.

Comment: excellent answer: accepted.